# unexpected character sequence in member name in a json document

Tags: json, visual-studio

I have a json document that looks more or less like this:

```
[
{
attr11:"value11",
attr12:"value12"
},
{
attr21:"value21",
attr22:"value22"
},
{
attr31:"value31",
attr32:"value32"
}
]
```

Visual Studio underlines the first letters of attrN and says "unexpected character sequence in member name". What is that?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio does not like member names which are not enclosed in quotation marks. Just enclose them in quotes:
{
  "attr11":"value11",
  "attr12":"value12"
},